# VB.NET Limit to Tab Ordering?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-interface, vb6-migration, tab-ordering

I have inherited a frankenstein VB6 "Converted" to VB.NET winform application. This application has a metric ton of fields in it, the users rightfully complained that the tab order is off (after a certain point it starts jumping all over the form).

Figuring something in tab order was off, I went in and turned on View > Tab Order and it looked good.

To be sure I went through the form again fresh and when I'm in tab order view all is well, but when the app runs it still starts jumping around the same area as before?! Has anyone else encountered this and how did you resolve if you did?

[Edit]: These input forms are all on separate tabs within a tab control, which probably muddies the situation even more.

Comment: You have my sympathies.  I've dealt with my share of vb6->vb.net madness as well, and it's not fun :(

Comment: @Joel & curtisk: I am feeling it as well. Do we need to start a support group? I have a lot of pain to share.

Comment: @Paul Sign me up, this thing is a groaner :p

Comment: @Paul I signed the question to the [vb6-migration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6-migration) tag. It's the closest thing to a support group that I know of...

Comment: @MarkJ thanks...good to know there are others out there that suffer :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are there any strange Focus calls in the code that are overriding the tab order and setting the focus of the application manually?

I've had problems in the past with tab ordering getting itself all confused and I've usually just resorted to going through the application from scratch and setting the order myself manually. I realise that this may well not be what you are looking for but I don't know of anything else

Comment: To say it was a "strange" focus call would be too nice, it was pretty whacked in what it was trying to validate and where the code resided, but that's ultimately what it was, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have many controls on a form chances are that they are organized with containers such as panels and group boxes. When setting the tab order you have to consider the order of the containers as well. An inconsistency between tab orders on in the containers could explain the weird jumping. This can happen especially if two or more controls/containers have the same tab order value which makes the tabbing process arbitrary.

*Solution Idea:* Of course updating and correcting the tab order is slow, error-prone work. It may behoove you to write a routine that iterates through the form's containers and controls recursively and assigning tab order values properly. You would set the tab order by comparing the Location point of each control of the container where top and left most point is the "lower" rank and the bottom, right-most component is the "highest". This would of course need a custom sorting alg. And if you look around, something like this may already be out there.

*Solution Idea 2:* Refactor! Divide and conquer. It will take some time but if you move the UI components into separate, logically-organized user controls you'll get tighter of the codebase. You'll also uncover a lot of bugs!

Comment: Good thought, but already covered that, they are in fact in logical grouping inside group boxes, and the group boxes order is correct, and the items below the group have the right 10.0.1, 10.0.2 type designation

Comment: Hmm. That middle zero in your example worries me though... How is that assigned and handled?

Comment: I'll update the main question but, these input forms are all on separate tabs(tab control) which probably compounds the pain :/

Comment: Only partly i think. Tabs should actually work like any other type of container. And i just added another suggestion to my answer: Refactor!

Answer (score 1):

Chances are, some of your controls are embedded in container controls, and the tab order of your container controls is causing the focus to appear as if it is jumping around randomly. Make sure that when you're in the tab order view, you pay careful attention to the tab order of your container controls: Make sure that none of them have the same tab order, and that they're ordered logically with the tab order of your individual controls.

Otherwise, you need to check your UI code for some calls to [`Control.Focus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx) that could be interfering with the default tab order at run-time. Some validation code may be changing the focus to the "next" control after it completes successfully (or "back" to a previous control if validation failed).

Comment: check my response to Paul, already been down the group path, but know I'll have to hunt for Focus jumps to see if that's the case